# Adding in Session Manual Term from GA4 to query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

How would I pull in Session Manual term to a query such as this

```
SELECT *
  FROM `nth-glider-369017.analytics_316822874.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) as param
 WHERE event_name IN ("sr_job_application_started", "sr_job_application_continued", "sr_job_completed_application")
   AND param.key IN ("term", "campaign", "source", "medium", "engaged_session_count")
   AND _table_suffix BETWEEN format_date('%Y%m%d',date_sub(current_date(), interval 30 day))
                         AND format_date('%Y%m%d',date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day));
```

I've tried adding in "term", but nothing is popping up, despite my UTM's having the UTMTerm value in them.

I also tried this, but got an error with "URL"

```
SELECT 
URL, REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'utm_content=([^&]+)') AS utm_content
FROM `nth-glider-369017.analytics_316822874.events_*`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_params) AS param
WHERE event_name IN ("sr_job_application_started", "sr_job_application_continued", "sr_job_completed_application")
  AND param.key IN ("term", "campaign", "source", "medium", "engaged_session_count")
  AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
                       AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```